# Changing Textbox from the cpp file

Tags: c++, visual-studio, textbox

What I'm trying to do is change a `textbox` from the `form1` from within the main '.cpp' file.

Basically, I want the text field to change on load. (Later it will be another reason).

Sorry if this is a dumb question. I'm a newbie.

I added the 2 lines in the Header file and changed the `textbox` from private to public. (guessing this isn't a good idea?)

Then I tried calling the change in the main function of the `.cpp` file.

Thank you so much for your help

`.cpp` file

```
// help.cpp : main project file.

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Form1.h"

using namespace help;

[STAThreadAttribute]
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    // Enabling Windows XP visual effects before any controls are created
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false); 

    // Create the main window and run it
    Application::Run(gcnew Form1());

    //Added this.
    Form1^ myform1 = gcnew Form1();
    Form1::myForm1->MyBox->Text = L" ShowME! ";


    return 0;
}
```

`form1.h` file

```
#pragma once

namespace help {
    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;

    /// <summary>
    /// Summary for Form1
    /// </summary>
    public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        static Form1^ myForm1; //Add this... 
        Form1(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            myForm1 = this; //added this...
            //
            //TODO: Add the constructor code here
            //
        }

    protected:
        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        ~Form1()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }
    public: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  MyBox; //Changed To Public..
    protected: 

    private:
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
            this->MyBox = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // MyBox
            // 
            this->MyBox->Location = System::Drawing::Point(20, 57);
            this->MyBox->Name = L"MyBox";
            this->MyBox->Size = System::Drawing::Size(247, 20);
            this->MyBox->TabIndex = 0;
            this->MyBox->TextChanged += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::MyBox_TextChanged);
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
            this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
            this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(284, 261);
            this->Controls->Add(this->MyBox);
            this->Name = L"Form1";
            this->Text = L"Form1";
            this->ResumeLayout(false);
            this->PerformLayout();

        }
#pragma endregion
    private: System::Void MyBox_TextChanged(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             }
    };
}
```

Update....

I'm still trying to figure it out. Today I woke up early to try again and I can't seem to get it to work.

I tried making a function called "go" on From1.h and then running the function from the cpp to see if it changes the box and nothing.

So then I decided to see if the function is running at all... Then I wrote a file and put hello in that file using the same function that suppose to update the textbox. It wrote the file no problem but the textbox is still unchanged Please Help!

cpp file

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Form1.h"

using namespace test6;

[STAThreadAttribute]
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{




    // Enabling Windows XP visual effects before any controls are created
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false); 


    Form1 peaches;
    peaches.go();



    // Create the main window and run it
    Application::Run(gcnew Form1());





    return 0;
}
```

Form1.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <String>
#pragma once

namespace test6 {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;


    /// <summary>
    /// Summary for Form1
    /// </summary>
    public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        Form1(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //
            //TODO: Add the constructor code here
            //



        }

        void go() {

            //This doesn't update the Box?
            MyBox->Text = ("Hello");


            //This does make a file with hello in it. 
            FILE * fname = fopen("text.txt","w");
            fprintf(fname, "Hello");
            fclose(fname);




        }

    protected:
        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        ~Form1()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  MyBox;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button1;
    protected: 

    private:
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
            this->MyBox = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->button1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // MyBox
            // 
            this->MyBox->Location = System::Drawing::Point(99, 112);
            this->MyBox->Name = L"MyBox";
            this->MyBox->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 20);
            this->MyBox->TabIndex = 0;
            this->MyBox->TextChanged += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::MyBox_TextChanged);
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this->button1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(110, 178);
            this->button1->Name = L"button1";
            this->button1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(75, 23);
            this->button1->TabIndex = 1;
            this->button1->Text = L"button1";
            this->button1->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
            this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
            this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(284, 261);
            this->Controls->Add(this->button1);
            this->Controls->Add(this->MyBox);
            this->Name = L"Form1";
            this->Text = L"Form1";
            this->ResumeLayout(false);
            this->PerformLayout();

        }
#pragma endregion
    private: System::Void MyBox_TextChanged(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             }
    };
}
```

Comment: I'm willing to pay if someone helps me with this. I already spent 2 days working on something that I would think would be easy.

Answer (score 2):

you can do this my setting the textbox text on the constructor of the form.

```
Form1(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            myForm1 = this; //added this... (?? no need)
            //
            //TODO: Add the constructor code here
            MyBox.Text = "Result is 22"; //where MyBox is your text box object.
        }
```

Note that :

No need to make text box public, as private members can be access within the class without any issue. (text box is defined inside the 'Form class' )

**Update to your second question:**

```
Form1 peaches; // obj1
peaches.go();

// Create the main window and run it
Application::Run(gcnew Form1());     // obj2
```

Look at your code, carefully. You have two distinct Form1 objects.
1. At `peaches` (obj1) you call `go)` function. Nothing happen because your UI not running at that moment.

2. Then you create another object with `gcnew Form1()` and lunching the UI. No change in UI, because you call `go()` in the other object.

Try this,

```
Form1 ^peaches = gcnew Form1(); 
// Create the main window and run it
Application::Run(peaches);
peaches->go();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I knew I could do it that way. However the cpp file will actually be doing some processing that I would then need to be able to transfer to the form1 text box.

Comment: No sadly. I'm lost at this point. I'm wondering if its even possible.